# Scatterplot with numbers as symbols (>9)

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to make a scatterplot of x and y with, as symbols, the values of the hour of the day at which x and y were measured. 
Passing the hour vector to `pch` works fine except that it refuses to plot numbers larger than 9.

```
(dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(144), y=rnorm(144), hour=rep(0:23, 6)))
plot(dat$x, dat$y, pch=as.character(dat$hour))
```

Is there an easy way out? thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `text` to begin with: `plot(NULL, xlim = range(dat$x), ylim = range(dat$y)); text(dat$x, dat$y, as.character(dat$hour))`

Comment: This is because `pch` stands for plotting *character*, not plotting text.